# Detect the state On/Off a DC 12V single coil latch relay

Tags: microcontroller, contactor

A LiFePo4 charging/discharging circuit (12 V, 200 Ah, 100 A max) is protected by a single coil latching relay with manual override. This relay is controlled by an ATMega328 (through a FET with flyback diode) but does not have state contacts. For safety and operational reasons, I would like to detect the open/close state of this relay and feed information back to the micro controller.

I have been so far considering measuring the differential voltage accross the contactor (<1 milliohm). This is somewhat simple but may fail if charging voltage equals the LiFePO4 battery (quite unlikely as CV/CC chargers will drive to ~14.4 V in absence of load). Contactor would be declared closed if voltage difference is less than 100 mV for some amount of time (~250 ms).

I am not certain of the type of differential amplifier and protections to use in these conditions:

- differential voltage range will be within -20 V/+20 V
- 50 V transients (+/-50 V) may exist during switching and load dumps

I would be very grateful if anyone could comment and criticize the approach and maybe advice on the kind of differential amplifier to select.

Best regards,

Edit:

- Manual override : the relay has an external push button to On/Off manually
- Schematic
  [image: Rough Schematic]

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you don't just monitor the coil voltage. It seems as though you do not trust the relay. 100 mV across a contact seems high.

> CV/CC chargers will drive to ~14.4V in absence of load.

That seems to me to be your solution. Use a comparator set to 14 V to monitor the PSU voltage. If it's over 14 V then you've an open circuit. If it's less then you're connected.

Comment: "manual override" could mean a mechanical button on the relay/contactor, bypassing the coil. A Schematic by OP would help disambiguating stuff like this.

Comment: @Transistor: the coil is energized only during 500ms to toggle the relay (On->Off or Off->On). The relay state can be manually changed by a mechanical push button. The 100mV across the contact may be obtained when reaching 100A. Uncertainties about the state of the relay exist in case of power down of the microcontroller and/or manual override hence the need to get a status.